# Why most of Microsoft Graph features are restricted to user access only

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Service or daemon authentication to the Microsoft Graph grants access to a limited number of functions.

For example, to be able to work with Planner and tasks, you have to be logged in as a user. In other case, we can't access most of user details, we can't access user's files and so on.

Why service or daemon must have more permissions then now? In our case, service should *automatically* create Planner tasks and Calendar events for specific users or groups according to *automatically* registered events. Sometimes it should also create or add or read files in OneDrive of this user. Also *automatically*, of course. Due to Microsoft Graph restrictions, it is easier to use additional 3rd-party service to track tasks, or even write our own. The same situation with files.

Microsoft Graph looks like a powerful API, but due to its access restrictions it becames unusable when you need to made something automatically, without any user actions.

What is the reason for most of these restrictions?
Is there any walkarounds?

Comment: This sounds more like feedback or a feature request vs. a dev question.  You can log requests for more permission scopes etc... here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 works perfect with deamon applications but not in your usecase. It works great for modifying a user' calendar for instance. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs

Apart from that, if you want to have something changed in the graph api. The best way to let Microsoft know is to create an item on UserVoice. This is to let users influence what features they need, maybe you can express your wishes there. https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests